# MS Teams tab app login is not working on IOS Teams App

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am building a Microsoft Teams tab app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) using React JS. My application has a login form that logs user in with Teams asking for additional permissions then send the access token back to the backend. My login form is working fine on Web and Desktop app version of the MS Teams. But it is not working on IOS MS Teams app.

This is how I login the user.

```
import {TeamsFx} from '@microsoft/teamsfx';

// rest of the code hidden

try {
   let teamsfx = new TeamsFx();
   const credentials = await teamsfs.getCredential();
   const accessToken = await credentials.getToken([ 'Group.Read.All', 'User.Read' ]);
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e.message)
}
```

when I login on the IOS Teams app, I am getting this error.

```
Unable to generate the SSO token: App is neither whitelisted nor app resource matches current domain.
```

What is the potential cause of the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the full code and substitute sensitive data with a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the app uri id as `api://{fullDomain}/{appId}` for you to be able to get tokens. And because you’re getting extra permissions, you need to make sure you are getting consent.